# Move image inside HTML canvas with mouse dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I have one image that I need to resize, move, and rotate inside a Canvas, and than another image that I use as a mask to clip the other image using `globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";`

Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rVx5G/1/)**.

I was thinking about to add buttons to move the image but why not the mouse? However, I can't find a way how to integrate a dragging function in this code. What do I need to change or hadd here?

Comment: I have updated to also show moving clipped region.

Comment: Another update to show clip and image. I think I am done now unless I have missed something :)

Comment: Thanks, The second fiddle is more/less what I need except the image (eagle) should be the ones moving and not the mask, and it should work when clicking the mouse and dragging.

But thanks anyway, I'll try to use your example and do the rest myself.

Comment: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/rVx5G/10/. I will update my answer too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Original - move outer image**

See this **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rVx5G/2/)**

Code:

```
$(window).mousemove(function(event) {
  $("#stcanvas").css({"left" : event.pageX, "top" : event.pageY});
});
```

css:

```
#stcanvas
{
    position:absolute;    
}
```

You would obviously add a button to enable movement. Alternatively, you may want to use jquery UI for in-built drag and drop.

**Update - move clip**

See **[this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rVx5G/3/)**.

If what you mean is that you would like to move the clip rather than the image, then do something like this:

```
$(window).mousemove(function(event) {
    var cWidth = $("#stcanvas").width();    
    moveXAmount = (event.pageX / $(window).width())*cWidth;    
    moveXAmount = moveXAmount - (cWidth/2);
    var cHeight = $("#stcanvas").height(); 
    moveYAmount = (event.pageY / $(window).height())*cHeight;    
    moveYAmount = moveYAmount - (cHeight/2);
    buildcanvas();
});
```

and in `make_pic` do this:

```
ctx.drawImage(mask_image, moveXAmount, moveYAmount);
```

**Update 2 - move clip and inner image**

see **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rVx5G/5/)**

If you want to move the image and the clip, then , basically you just add the moveXAmount and moveYAmount to drawImage. Hopefully I have exhausted all possibilities now ;)

```
ctx.drawImage(pic_image, -400 / 2+moveXAmount, -550 / 2+moveYAmount, im_width, im_height);
```

**Update 3 move image and not mask as per comment**

See **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rVx5G/10/)**

The main change is:

```
$("#stcanvas").mousedown(function(){
    isDragging = true;
});

$(window).mouseup(function(){
    isDragging = false;
});
```

Comment: I got it working as I need, thanks to you. 
[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rVx5G/9/)

Comment: @user1977790 - excellent. The only change I would recommend is that `$("#stcanvas").mouseup(` should be `$(window).mouseup` otherwise if you move the mouse out of the image when you mouseup the image will continue to drag when you next go over the image even with the mouse up. Hopefully that makes sense. My final update shows this.

Comment: When we click in the picture to drag, the image assumes the initial position, and also when we drag the image it doesn't move along with the mouse, there's some kind of increasing delay. 
I tried to turn around this, but I'm not that good with math to come up with the right formula. 
Any idea how can this be solved?

Comment: It sounds like you want to track the delta in the mouse movements, probably best handled in a separate question. If you create a new question and put the link in the comments here I will take a look.

Comment: Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21999718/moving-image-in-canvas-with-mouse