# HTML5 moving image with mouse

Tags: jquery, html

1) Load a 200px portrait or landscape image into canvas. (400px width, 200px height) or (200px width, 400px height)

Get one here:
http://placekitten.com/g/400/200
http://placekitten.com/g/200/400

2) Let user drag image left or right for landscapes photos and up and down for portrait photos.
3) Don't let the user move the image out of view.

ISSUES:

1) When you click, hold, and drag the mouse it moves the image.  I was able to get the image to stop movement if at the edge.

The problem is that it's storing the cursor position after movement stops, so when you attempt a new drag it is as if the image was moved way out of view where you left off. (Difficult to describe, easy to duplicate in http://jsfiddle.net/hzkveg4u/2/ fiddle.)

Here is the code for detecting if the landscape image has been horizontally scrolled all the way to the edge: I am stumped as to why it is storing the PrevX after the edge has been met.

```
$(window).mousemove(function(event) {
    if( isDragging == true ) {
        if( prevX>0 || prevY>0) {
            moveXAmount += event.pageX - prevX;
            moveYAmount += event.pageY - prevY;
            buildcanvas();
        }

    var moveRight = -200 / 2 + moveXAmount + pic_image.width - 200; 
        if ( moveRight <= 0 ) {
            prevX = event.pageX;
            prevY = event.pageY;
            return false;
        //  prevX=0;
        } else {
        prevX = event.pageX;
        prevY = event.pageY;
        }
    }
});
```

2) The mousedown/drag event is highlighting text and objects, this is unwanted.

A lot of this code was borrowed from this stackoverflow question:
[Moving image in canvas with mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21999718/moving-image-in-canvas-with-mouse/21999834#21999834)

Comment: Sorry if I am being a bit dense here, can you describe the problem a bit more. I am able to move side-to-side and stop and then start again with no visual problems

Comment: Yah sure np. Thanks for looking. The problem is say you load up the 200x400 image. Then drag it to left until it stops. Then keep draging the mouse even though the canvas stopped moving. Now, try to grab the image and move it back to the right. You might notice that you have to scroll a few seconds extra to get it to start moving again.

Comment: I understand now I am getting it, thanks - having a look...

Comment: Sounds good I have found a fix for a portrait scrolled to top...creating new fiddle with my updated code. http://jsfiddle.net/hzkveg4u/3/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hzkveg4u/4/

Answer (score 1):

I  have fixed it as I understand the issue, please try below,

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hzkveg4u/7/)

**JS**

```
$(window).mousemove(function(event) {
    if( isDragging == true )
    {

        console.log("prev x: " + prevX);
        console.log("prev y: " + prevY);
        console.log("current x: " + event.pageX);
        console.log("current y: " + event.pageY); 
        console.log("move x amount: " + moveXAmount);
        console.log("move y amount: " + moveYAmount);

        var w = pic_image.width;
        var h = pic_image.height;

        if( (prevX>(w / 2) && prevX < w) || (prevY>(h / 2) && prevY < h))
        {
            moveXAmount += event.pageX - prevX;
            moveYAmount += event.pageY - prevY;
            buildcanvas();
        }

        var moveRight = -200 / 2 + moveXAmount + pic_image.width - 200; 
        if ( moveRight <= 0 ) {

            prevX = event.pageX;
            prevY = event.pageY;
            return false;
        //  prevX=0;
        } else {

            prevX = event.pageX;
            prevY = event.pageY;
        }
    }
});
```